# order div breakpoint mobile Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following order in the desktop version:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make Content 2 appear first in mobile?

Comment: Check: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`order-first`** and **`orader-md-0`** classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes) for the `content 2` column.

**`order-first`** orders the column first in the row. While **`order-md-0`** resets the `order` of the column when the `md` breakpoint is reached.

There is no way to order the  columns for mobile only because bootstrap has removed all the variants of `*-xs-*` classes. Therefore, you need to use both of classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-first order-md-0 col-md-5">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

### https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKRVWN

You have not used `col-*` for small size screen. So I used `col-12`.

Comment: `col-12` isn't needed. It will stack automatically on smaller screens. See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically have to use Bootstrap, then a simple flex layout will sort this.

There is a specific `order` option:

https://codepen.io/n8udd/pen/eKgONQ